# How to reduce camera image filesize in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I need to capture photo from camera and save it in folder.If i tried to display  multiple images from folder. It is not loading, throwing memory warning and close the app.If i choose image from Photo Library , this process is working properly. Where i missed out Please advice.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    isPrivacyPhoto = NO;
    UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; 
    NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage,1.0);
        [jpegData  writeToFile:fileDirectory atomically:NO];


}


thumnail = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",photo.Path,photo.PhotoName]];

thumnail=[appDelegate thumnail scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(75.0, 104.0)];



-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

I have attached my source code for your reference:

```
for (int Count = 0; Count < [listData count]  ; Count ++)
{
    Photo *photo = [listData objectAtIndex: Count];

    if([FileUtils fileExistsAtPath:photo.Path fileName:photo.PhotoName])
    {

        PhotoView *photoView = [[PhotoView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(ThumbnailSizeWidth * (PhotoViewCount % THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING * (PhotoViewCount % THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING,
                                                                            ThumbnailSizeHeight * (PhotoViewCount / THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING * (PhotoViewCount / THUMBNAIL_COLS) + PADDING + PADDING_TOP,
                                                                            ThumbnailSizeWidth,
                                                                            ThumbnailSizeHeight)];
        [photoView setDelegate:self];
        [photoView setPhoto:photo];
        [photoView setTagIndexID:OrginalCounter];   
        //NSLog(@"TagIndexID:%d",Count);
        PhotoViewCount ++ ;


        if(photo.isPrivacy)
        {
            UIImage *tImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locked.png"];
            [photoView setPhotoViewImage:tImage];
        }
        else
        {
            [photoView setTag:OrginalCounter];

            NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",photo.Path,photo.PhotoName]];
            UIImage *thumnail = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];


            //UIImage *thumnail = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",photo.Path,photo.PhotoName]];
            //UIImage *thumnail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",photo.Path,photo.PhotoName]];

            MyPhoto *photo = [[MyPhoto alloc] initWithImage:thumnail];
            [photos addObject:photo];
            [photo release];
            //[thumnail release];


            OrginalCounter++;

            [photoView performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setPhotoViewImage:) withObject:thumnail];

        }

        [scrollViewer addSubview:photoView];
        [photoView release];


    }
}




-(void) setPhotoViewImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];


    PrivacyPixAppDelegate *appDelegate = [PrivacyPixAppDelegate appDelegate];

    image=[appDelegate imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(75.0, 104.0)];
    //image = [image scaleAndCropToSize:CGSizeMake(69.0, 104.0) onlyIfNeeded:YES];
    //image =   [image scaleAndCropToSize:CGSizeMake(75, 100)];

    //image=[image ScaleImageToRect:image displaySize:CGSizeMake(40,40)];


    if(!btnPhoto)
        btnPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [btnPhoto setFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 75, 75)];
    //[btnPhoto setContentMode:UIViewContentModeTop];
    btnPhoto.image = image;
    [self addSubview:btnPhoto];
    //[btnPhoto release];


    if(!txtPhotoName)
        txtPhotoName = [[UITextField alloc] init];

        [txtPhotoName setDelegate:self];
    [txtPhotoName setFrame:CGRectMake(2, btnPhoto.frame.size.height + 2, self.frame.size.width, 20)];
    txtPhotoName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    txtPhotoName.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    txtPhotoName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    txtPhotoName.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
    txtPhotoName.text = photo.PhotoCaption;
    txtPhotoName.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    txtPhotoName.hidden = YES;
    [self addSubview:txtPhotoName];


    if(!lblPhotoName)
        lblPhotoName = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        [lblPhotoName setFrame:CGRectMake(0, btnPhoto.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, 25)];
    lblPhotoName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblPhotoName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0];
    lblPhotoName.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    lblPhotoName.text = photo.PhotoCaption;
    lblPhotoName.numberOfLines = 2;
    lblPhotoName.hidden = NO;
    lblPhotoName.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:lblPhotoName];



    //[lblPhotoName release];

    [pool release];
}


-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    // Create a bitmap context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

This is my code, am getting memory waring and app crash. Where i have to change it.
Note: App crash happens only the Camera image.

: Received memory warning. Level=2

Comment: do you want to crop image ???

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this post: [How do I reduce Image quality/size in iPhone objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079543/how-do-i-reduce-image-quality-size-in-iphone-objective-c)

You can create a graphics context, draw the image into that at the desired scale, and use the returned image. For example:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480,320));
CGContextRef            context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
UIImage        *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Just modify the size above to reduce the image to whatever you like.

Comment: Please review my full source and guide me